# How do i Prevent remote file inclusion attack from php?

Tags: php

This is my code in index.php

```
include ($_GET['page']);
```

Actully i need to include page from url like

```
"?page=go.php"
```

on the other-hand i can not filter

```
"?page=example.com"
```

as for some case i need to include this value also. But this is a remote file inclusion (RFI) vulnerability. how can i prevent RFI attack from my site?
I am doing something like

```
$filename = $_GET['page'];
if (file_exists($filename)) {
{
include ($_GET['page']);
}
```

But it filters only

```
"?page=go.php"
```

this shorts of page.
And i am sucked with

```
"?page=example.com"
```

this shorts of page.

Comment: why not config a list of accessible pages to validate against?

Comment: I cannot Make a list like this because there is no limitation of accessible pages, users will put there links and i will grab some information from that.

Comment: you can produce a list of accessible pages using directory read functions in php.

Comment: `I need to include ?page=example.com also` - why? Sounds like the problem is the design, not the question.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly; You could setup an array with 'allowed' pages such as:

```
  $allowedPages = array('go.php', 'stop.php', 'file.php');
  $filename = $_GET['page'];

  if(in_array($filename, $allowedPages) && file_exists($filename)){
    include ($filename);
  }else{
    //output error
  }
```

Comment: I cannot Make a list like this because there is no limitation of accessible pages, users will put there links and i will grab some information from that.

Comment: Well that would impose a massive security risk, there needs to be a whitelist as it is user input - and the user input is 'executing' a file that is on your server. You can understand that not having a whitelist can unveil all sorts of things about your website.

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer is too late, but for those who might search for this problem, I guess it can be done like this, too:

1.Define a constant with full path.

2.Define a white-list of allowed pages.

3.Get the $_GET variable, and convert it to lower case.

4.Then if the page returned by $_GET variable is in your white-list array, then require it, otherwise, redirect the user to the home page, and display an error message.

```
<?php
# this is abcd.php
define('SITE','http://www.yoursite.com/');
$allow = [SITE.'1.php', SITE.'2.php', SITE.'3.php'];
$get = strtolower(SITE.$_GET['page']);

if(in_array($get,$allow)){
    include $get;
} else {
    header('Location: index.php?param=incorrect');
}
?>

<?php
# this is index.php
if(isset($_GET['param']) && $_GET['param'] == 'incorrect'){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("INCORRECT PARAMETER PROVIDED");
    </script>
<?php
} else die('ERROR');
```

I'm not 100% sure this will work without any probs, but I guess is a good start and you can play around with it and figure out what's suitable for you.

Comment: Dan Costinel's answer has a vulnerability. If a user inputs the following example: http://maliciouswebsite.com/malicious.php?http://www.yoursite.com/ (everything after `?`, is ignored)
the website would still detect `http://www.yoursite.com/`, and not block its connection allowing arbitrary execution.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, your method of creating a `dynamic` website is definitely not the way to go.

To answer within the scope of this question, you'd do something like the following:

You'd have to set up a `whitelist` of files that are**ALLOWED** to be included through this function.

That could look something like this:

```
<?php 

$whitelist = array(
    'file1.php',
    'file2.php',
    'file3.php',
    'file4.php',
    'file5.php',
);

?>
```

Now before including the said file, you'd run a check with [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/in_array)

```
<?php 

if(in_array($_GET['page'] . '.php', $whitelist) && file_exists($_GET['page'] . '.php')) {
    include($_GET['page'] . '.php');
}

?>
```

This, as you can see is not very pretty!
Another alternative would be doing something like:

```
    <?php 
    $file = strtolower($_GET['page']) . '.php';
    if(isset($whitelist[$file]) && file_exists($file)) {
        include($_GET['page'] . '.php');
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: I cannot Make a list like this because there is no limitation of accessible pages, users will put there links and i will grab some information from that.

Comment: @user1487328 Then you seriously need to rethink your approach to this.

Comment: @user1487328 there must be some limitation - what is the scope of what you're trying to do? what's to stop users doing `?go=/var/www/othersiteonsameserver/htdocs/secret.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't accept a page.php parameter, but just the name of the file.

```
"?page=go"
```

Then check if $_REQUEST["page"] is alphanumeric

```
if (ctype_alnum($_REQUEST["page"]))
```

And just don't give non-alpha-numeric names to your files.

Then do if file_exists on $_REQUEST["page"] and you should be quite good.

PS 
$_REQUEST["page"] is about the same with $_GET["page"], it just intersects with $_POST

Comment: It also intersects with $_COOKIE, by default. It it needs to be used with some care.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter other domain urls instead of filtering files.
If parameter contains a hostname less than 3 letters, it is fine as no domain is 2 letters.

```
   $tmp= parse_url ($_GET['page']);
   if(strlen($tmp['host'])<3)
    include($_GET['page']);
```

If there are some trusted hosts then you can validate them too.