# How to Protect my webapp from Local file include vulnerability?

Tags: php

i wanna protect my webapp from local file include vulnerability ,
so i create this protection mechanism:

```
$file = $_REQUEST ['file'];
$file = str_replace('..' , '' , $file);
$file = str_replace('/' , '' , $file);
$file = str_replace('\\' , '' , $file);
```

so if the attacker try to use ../ it will not include any file ,
is this a good way ? or it can bypassed , if so , how ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i Prevent remote file inclusion attack from php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776822/how-do-i-prevent-remote-file-inclusion-attack-from-php)

Comment: @bravemaster , no no its a different question , i'm asking for my way , is it safe or not ?

Comment: It's still unsafe. Whitelist approach is always better than blacklist for security. In that context, the answers from the question that I suggested are the most suitable ways.